# Is it possible to move wordpress out of webroot?

Tags: php, apache

Is there a way to put the wordpress out of webroot dir, and just leave a entry index.php to the webroot?

Comment: I know how to move wordpress to a subdirectory, but the subdirectory is still need to be under the webroot, what i mean is to move the wordpress lib file out of webroot completely.

Comment: This page should give you what you need. http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory